# Why are the php variables not working with my Javascript/Laravel-5 Google Maps Code?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm working on a laravel-5 application which requires me to sync data from a database and display it on google maps. The problem that I'm encountering is that whenever I run the code, it gives me an error that says:

> Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\appl\resources\views\getmap6.blade.php)

The code for my page is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>                  

<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCVL8zAciHqjdNLW6oPyKZSfNvCgrL9D5A"></script>
<script>

            function initialize() 
                {
                    var mapProp = {
                                    center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
                                    zoom:13,
                                    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                                  };

                    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
                    var infowindow = null;

                    <?php for($i=1; $i<3; $i++)
                            {
                                $offLinks = App\offerlink::find($i);
                    ?>            

                    var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                                                position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $offLinks->lat; ?>,<?php echo $offLinks->lng; ?>),
                                                icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
                                             });

                    marker.setMap(map);

                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                                                content: "<b>Name: </b>" + "<?php echo $offLinks->name; ?>" + "<br> <b>Address: </b>" + "<?php echo $offLinks->address; ?>",
                                                            });



                    infowindow.open(map,marker);

                                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

                                                                                infowindow.setContent(marker);
                                                                                infowindow.open(map,this);
                                                                              });

                            <?php } ?>  


                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

                                                                                infowindow.setContent(marker);
                                                                                infowindow.open(map,this);
                                                                              });       

                }

                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

This code works on a local server which syncs to a phpMyAdmin database. The other pages don't have any issues when trying to connect to the database. It is only this page that has the issue. I know that the problem lies in the following lines of the code because because without those lines, there are no errors:

```
position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $offLinks->lat; ?>,<?php echo $offLinks->lng; ?>),
```

and

```
content: "<b>Name: </b>" + "<?php echo $offLinks->name; ?>" + "<br> <b>Address: </b>" + "<?php echo $offLinks->address; ?>",
```

Clearly, there is something wrong in the way I'm trying to use the php variables. I believe this code was working fine a few days ago.

Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: Is that error coming from PHP or JavaScript?  Which specific line of code is actually producing the error?  Where do you expect that object to be initialized?

Comment: In the question, I've specifically mentioned the two lines that seem to be producing the error.

Comment: So then $offLink is not an object?  Sounds like the line which sets it is returning null or false or something of that nature.  Doesn't seem like this code would have much to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wrongly accessing the php variables.
Just try the following..

```
$offLinks[$i]->name
```

Comment: I'm using the same format for accessing database data on other pages of my application and it works fine. I tried to use your format as well but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your model call `$offLinks = App\offerlink::find($i)` is not returning any results for `$i` and therefore `$offLinks` is not a valid object. try confirming that `$offLinks` is indeed an object by using `dump($offLinks)`. Or you can simply chang the call to `$offLinks = App\offerlink::findOrFail($i)` which will give you a clear error if no model is found.